# Using GeoJSON offline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson

I have some GEOJSON-Layers in my QGIS-project. The problem is, that when I zoom in or out, it takes very long to built up the window again. That's because it always loads it from the server. But I don't need that. It's enough, just to load it when I start the project and the handle it like a shapefile. Of course, I can save the WMS-Layer as a shapefile. But doing this everyday with every WMS-Layer would me to much work.

Is there an easy solution?

Comment: You can't save WMS layer as a shapefile because WMS layer is an image, not vector data. You could save the image as an georeferenced image (GeoTÌFF or png, jpeg etc. with a world file) but that would cover only the view that you had on screen and at fixed resolution. If the WMS server that you use supports WMS-C tiled mode (GeoServers are often configured for that) it might be possible to collect a local cache on your computer. There are other solutions as well, but not anything I would call especially easy. WMS is meant to be used on-line.

Comment: Ah damn. Sorry. I mixed to different problems in my brain. I mean GOJSON files.

Comment: From what kind of server those GeoJSON files are coming from?

Comment: I use an Ipad with the Fulcrum App for mapping landslides. The "waypoints" I create there are synchronized with QGIS via GEOJSON. Then I got hundreds of points with different informations. My goal is to ynchronize it, the morning after I went mapping and have it then offline. As I said before: It would be great, not having to sve it as a shape file but just to say: "Stop synchronizing, and just keep it as it wa when i synchronized it the last time" :-)

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know Fulcrum and do not get the whole picture. Is it that you are reading data in GeoJSON format from some Fulcrum server with QGIS? Could you simply download the same GeoJSON into a local file every morning and open that with QGIS?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I do. I think, downloading the whole file in a local one is possible. I just hoped that there is hidden possibility to work with the existing GeoJSON in an offline mode.

Comment: Could you give some more help? How do you access the Fulcrum data right now with QGIS? Do you point it to some URL or server? What makes it to read all the data from the server every time you pan or zoom? If you have a local GeoJSON file that does not happen so I have a feeling that the title of your question may be misleading and it should perhaps be "how to use Fulcrum service/API off-line".

Answer (score 2):

GeoJSON is just a file format. While it might often be downloaded from remote servers on-the-fly, there is nothing in the spec dictating that. You need to figure out how to save the file locally, then you can simply load it in QGIS.